# Plugin для Sublime Text, с помощью которого можно создавать файлы

Tags: sublime-text

Я как то видел плагин, с помощью которого можно было в редакторе создавать файлы и папки, там как-то вызывалась панель, и в нее можно было писать название папки или файла, и они создавались.

Но я не помню название и не знаю, как найти.

Comment: SideBarEnhancements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте этот плагин [AdvancedNewFile](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AdvancedNewFile)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот еще один, но этот не пробовал [Quick File Creator](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Quick%20File%20Creator)

Comment: спасибо большое Quick File Creator - больше прикольнее :)

Answer (score 0):

А точно плагин нужен? Если вы об этой панели - то просто перетащите папку в Sublime
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот плагин у меня есть, да там тоже можно создавать файлы и папки, но что бы создать, это надо навести на папку, нажать клавишу, создать папку потом еще раз навести и создать файл, и тд.

а есть плагин, где открывается панель и там можно написать что то типу: folder/template/file.html
ну как то так, и все будет